# About Parse API Data

Tags: javascript, php, api

The API returns data like this:

```
data({"total" : 100, "totalPage" : 10, "page" : 2, "items" : ["data"]})
```

How to parse this? For example, I want to get totalPage, How to do this? Use PHP or  JavaScript.

Comment: Where are you going to receive the data?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I get this data in php use file_get_contents()

Comment: $data = file_get_contents('your url') ; $data = json_decode($data);

Comment: Are you sure you get that with the `data(` and `)` around it?

Comment: And what API do you use?

Comment: @Rizier123 The `data()` is very common - it's almost certainly a [JSONP callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, I found that there is a defined function in the js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it's a jsonp data~~

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP

```
$str = <<<JSON
{"total" : 100, "totalPage" : 10, "page" : 2, "items" : ["data"]}
JSON;

$json = json_decode($str);

echo $json->totalPage;
```

Comment: You use other data than OP receives.

Comment: But there is data( ) around it.